# Primary Key returning 0 - MVC core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, primary-key

I am trying to get the value of the primary key of my model

However I get 0

My code is

```c
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    context.Upload_Transaction.Add(upload_Transaction);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    id = Upload_Transaction.Upload_TransactionID; 
    ViewData["id"] = id; // For some reason this returns 0
}
```

Comment: Did you debug `upload_Transaction`? What values does it have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your code from;

```
id = Upload_Transaction.Upload_TransactionID;
```

to

```
id = upload_Transaction.Upload_TransactionID;
```

Then that should fix the issue. You are trying to read the new ID from the wrong object.

Comment: silly me, thanks for the update